# Integrating Solr using PHP

Tags: php, search, solr

I wanted to use Solr in order to enable a Learning Management Service package have search features. I read and tried out the official tutorial from here: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_0/tutorial.html.
and here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr

What should I use: [SolPHP](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP) or [KoPHP](https://github.com/Yehuda-Daniel/PHP-Apache-Solr-Adapter)

However, I couldn't think how to integrate Solr into the PHP package.

What files will I have to include in the package and what modifications will I need to do to enable Solr indexing and search?

Any help/post/relevant tutorial will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Integration  Solarium with PHP

1.download  and install php web server(XAMPP)

2.set PHP path in envirement varibale(C:\xampp\php)

3.downlaod and install composer (change compatibilty if program crasshed )

4.open file "C:\xampp\php\php.ini" and uncomment  extension=php_curl.dll and  extension=php_openssl.dll

5.when composer is install succesfully(C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin) there is composer.phar file available or download composar.phar file

6.open command prompt and goto your composer.phar file path ,create a file name composer.json (php composar.phar init)

#

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\RKJ>cd C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin
C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin>php composer.phar init
Welcome to the Composer config generator
This command will guide you through creating your composer.json config.
 Package name (<vendor>/<name>) [RKJ/bin]: a/b
 Description []:
Author:
Minenter code hereimum Stability []:
License []:
Define your dependencies.
Would you like to define your dependencies (require) interactively [yes]? no
Would you like to define your dev dependencies (require-dev) interactively [yes]
? no
{
    "name": "a/b",
   "require": {
 }
 }
Do you confirm generation [yes]? yes
```

then edit your composer.json file and  update require feild to  "solarium/solarium":    "3.0.0"

or
    save  file as composer.json
    {
    "name": "rkj/abc",
    "require": {
         "solarium/solarium": "3.0.0"
               }
    }

7.type >>php composer.phar install  a vendor foler will be available in your path

8.copy vandor folder into your php workspace(C:\xampp\htdocs) and check using following script

```
<?php
$config = array(
'endpoint' => array(
    'localhost' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost', 'port' => '8080', 'path' => '/solr/collection1/select? 
    q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true'
      )
    )
 );

// new Solarium Client object
include(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);
print('helllo<br>');
$ping = $client->createPing();

// execute the ping query
try{
$result = $client->ping($ping);
echo 'Ping query successful';
echo '<br/><pre>';
var_dump($result->getData());
}catch(Solarium\Exception $e){
echo 'Ping query failed';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For integrating php with Solr, solarium can be used. Solarium provides is very well built and provides a huge set of features for using Solr from php. Also solarium is well maintained as compared to other options like SolPhp.

Here is a book which gives a good idea of how the integration works and how to go about utilizing all the features of Solr using php.

http://www.packtpub.com/apache-solr-php-integration/book